# Can't read csv automatically with R(D)COM

Tags: c#, r

I have a problem when trying to read .csv file with `STATCONNECTORSRVLib (R(D)COM)`.

When I enter this code lines, it works:

```
    var sc1 = new STATCONNECTORSRVLib.StatConnector();
    sc1.Init("R");
    sc1.EvaluateNoReturn("dataset=read.csv(file.choose())");
```

A pop up windows is opened, I choose file from `c:\\` , it loads, and I can do calculation with it.

However, when I enter this almost exact code:

```
    var sc1 = new STATCONNECTORSRVLib.StatConnector();
    sc1.Init("R");
    sc1.EvaluateNoReturn("dataset=read.csv('C:\\output.csv')");
```

I get this annoying exception:

```
"The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"
```

The line `dataset=read.csv('C:\\output.csv')` works fine in R console.

What am I doing wrong, and how can my machine read file when I'm uploading manualy, but not automaticly?

I'm using: `R 2.13.1` from RandFriend pack, and have all that is included within it.
OS Windows 7, 64 bit
All my projects in the solution are .NET 4, x86

Comment: Shot in the dark. Is it possibly a permissions issue i.e. trying to read from C: root. Try placing a file in your home directory and reading that.

Comment: thanx, it was actually a permission problem. When I placed the file in C:\temp and changed the string accordingly it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I think C# is treating converting your double backslashes to a single backslash, which R is then interpreting as an escape sequence.  Try changing your  string to

```
"dataset=read.csv('C:\\\\output.csv')"
```

or

```
@"dataset=read.csv('C:\\output.csv')"
```

or

```
"dataset=read.csv('C:/output.csv')"
```